# Scheduling loop

Tags: computer-architecture, scheduling, loops

[image: Click here] I do not understand how do you write schduled loop from unscheduled one. The unscheduled loop straightforward if you follow the stall rules.

The rules say you are supposed to stall after L.D but in the right loop theres no stall.

Comment: You do not stall after a load. You only stall after a load if the next instruction uses the result of the load. On the right side the next instruction doesn't use the result of the load, therefore no stall.